# How can I show this language is context free by constructing a context free grammar?

Tags: grammar, context-free-grammar, automata, finite-automata, context-free-language

How can I construct a context free grammar for the following language:

L = {0^n1^nx | n >= 1, and x ∈ {0, 1}*}

This language is that some number of zeros followed by same number of ones then some number of bit strings.
I was thinking I need S -> 0S1 for the 0^n1^n part and A -> 0A | 1A | e for the x ∈ {0, 1}*.
Since I need some bit strings after same number of zeros and ones, I did

S -> 0S1A | e

A -> 0A | 1A | e

But the grammar accepts 0001101, which is not correct. There are 3 0's and only 2 1's.
I am new to CFG's. Can someone give me a tip for this language?

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you have a language which can be decomposed into the concatenation of two sublanguages, construct the two languages separately and then concatenate them:

```
S → A B
A → …
B → …
```

In this case, A will be 0<sup>n</sup>1<sup>n</sup> and B will be {0, 1}<sup>*</sup>.

Comment: @asdf: just in case: A cannot be empty so its base case must be 01. B can be empty so its base case (omitted in your comment) is empty.

Comment: Thank you so much. Yes I had A -> e and that was why I ended up having strings start with 1. S -> A  B      A -> 0A1 | 01    B -> 0B | 1B | e. This is what I have now and looks fine. Thanks again